# How to hover one containers over another in Bootstrap3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to implement the following design in bootstrap3.

Does anyone know how to hover the container2 over the container1? 
I can use the position:absolute way but I think there must be a better way to do it.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.container-1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.container-2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -50px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container container-1">...</div>
<div class="container container-2">...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this seems OK. And one more question, how can I do this effect with rows in one container ?

Comment: Just use `.row-n` instead of `.container-n` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin-top on the "container 2" to get this effect

```
.container-2 {
    margin-top: -200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mwo8jdeL/

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxKfW.png

Index.html

```
 [![<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row one">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row two">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>][1]][1]
```

CSS File

```
.one{
    background-color: red;
    height: 400px;
}

.two{
    background-color: green;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
}
```